# Trying to append info to a column of a csv file (without pandas)

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to append information to a column of a csv file. I have a folder of texts and I loop through the folder adding the percentage of words (a float) to the csv under a header titled "percentage". The csv file already has other headers and rows containing info like text title, year, id. My code compiles but does not change the (append to) the csv file.

```py
with open(sys.argv[2]) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    os.chdir(sys.argv[1])
    for row in reader:
        text = row["id"] + ".txt"  
        if text in novel_folder:
           (omitted this code to save time (calc perc)
           with open(csvfile, "a") as csvfile2:
           writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile2,fieldnames=["percentage"])
           writer.writerow({"percentage":  perc})
```

I change directories because the texts are in a folder within my working directory. I then loop through every row in the csv and if the id (name of text) for that row is in the text folder (sys.argv[1]) I calculate the percentage (omitted) and then append that percentage to the 'percentage' header in the csv. Sys.argv[2] is the csv file name while sys.argv[1] is the text folder name.

This is what the first row of the csv file looks like (the headers):

```
author,id,title,year,percentage
```

Comment: Can you fix indentation and those backslashes in your sample?

Answer (score 1):

You can't append a column to a CSV file. Instead, you need to rewrite entire rows with the extra data you want. You could open the target output file once and write as you process the rows. Get the existing field names from the CSV file you read and then use those field names plus the extra "percentage" column when you write.

It's usually better not to change directories in a program. It's easy to keep longer file names and you don't run the risk of messing with any relative path names in use.

```
in_name = sys.argv[2]
out_name = os.path.join(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])

with open(in_name) as csvfile, open(out_name, "a") as csvout:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvout, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames + ["percentage"])
    for row in reader:
        text = row["id"] + ".txt"  
        if text in novel_folder:
            perc = (omitted this code to save time \*\* all it did was calculate percentage)
            row["percentage"] = perc
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense thank you. What is the purpose of the 2nd line, "out_name = os.path.join...."?

Comment: Also, I tried not changing directories, but I encountered a FileNotFoundError because all the texts I want to access are in their own folder within my workspace. Any suggestions for that? Also, I re ran my code and it does what it is supposed to except it does not write the new rows to the csv file. I printed the rows out and they do have a new column with percentage, but the csv file does not change.